# Getting "A local variable named X cannot be declared in this scope" error in Unity 5

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error in unity:

> 5.50f3
>   Assets/Scripts/BaseClient/client.c s(14701,12): error CS0136: A local variable named 'text' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'text', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else

Here is snippet of code:

```
case 126: 

//String text = inStream.readString(); 
int frame = inStream.method435(); 
if (text.StartsWith("www.")) 
{ 
    //openURL(text); 
    pktType = -1; return true; 
} 
if(text != null && frame != null) 
{ 
    updateStrings(text, frame); 
    sendFrame126(text, frame); 
} 
if (frame >= 18144 && frame <= 18244) 
{ 
    //clanList[frame - 18144] = text; 
} 
pktType = -1; return true;
```

Comment: case 126:
    //String text = inStream.readString();
    int frame = inStream.method435();
    if (text.StartsWith("www.")) {
     //openURL(text);
     pktType = -1;
     return true;
    }
    if(text != null && frame != null)
    {
    updateStrings(text, frame);
    sendFrame126(text, frame);
    }
    if (frame >= 18144 && frame <= 18244) {
     //clanList[frame - 18144] = text;
    }
    pktType = -1;
    return true;

Comment: This is not how to ask a question. Edit your question and add that code to it. If I were you, I would actually add the whole code inside client.cs since a variable is likely declared twice.

Comment: off-topic: I hope that you do not have a switch-case statement with 100+ cases

Comment: Pro-tips: (a) code does not render well in comments, always add it to your question; (b) if you have commented-out code, consider removing it, so that readers are not distracted by code that does not run; (c) refrain from adding "please help" and "frustrated" begging messages, especially in your title; (d) use the formatting tools provided to make the question clearer, e.g. a quote block for the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is simply letting you know that you are reusing the same name for two variables:

int myVar = 0;  // this one is global to the class

void Start()
{
    int myVar = 20; // local variable, same name => problem
}

other case is within statement

```
if(condA)
{
    int myResult = MethodA();
}
else
{
    int myResult = MethodB();
}
```

This is likely what you are facing. Either give a different name in each subsection or get the variable out:

```
int myResult = -1;
if(condA)
{
    myResult = MethodA();
}
else
{
    myResult = MethodB();
}
```

This is likely what you are facing. Either give a different name in each